# Why does this merge produce a conflict

Tags: git

When I run this command:

```
 git log HEAD..other_branch -- some_file.txt
```

There's no output at all which I assume meants that there were no changes to `some_file.txt` in `other_branch`.  Yet when I run `git merge other_branch` I get a whole slew of conflicts in `some_file.txt.`

When I run:

```
git log HEAD...other_branch -- some_file.txt
```

I get two commits. One where the file was modified and one where the branch where it was modified was merged into `HEAD.`

I assumed that because the file was only changed in one branch that there wouldn't be any conflicts. Why are there conflicts?  Is there a way to see what will conflict (and why) before I run `git merge`?

Answer (score 4):

To add to manojlds's contribution:

Very nice. But then the following should accomplish the same?

```
git diff master:some_file.txt someBranch:some_file.txt
```

that way you don't need to checkout before diffing against cached

---

Original answer:

The command

```
git log HEAD..other_branch -- some_file.txt
```

is identical to

```
git log ^HEAD other_branch -- some_file.txt
```

which means give me the log of all commits reachable from other_branch but NOT reachable from HEAD for some_file.txt. If this command gives you no output, it means that some_file.txt has not changed on other_branch at all.

On the other hand:

```
git log HEAD...other_branch -- some_file.txt
```

is the symmetric difference between HEAD and other_branch, i.e. the commits that are in HEAD and in other_branch but not in both, and are the commits that will be merged when you merge the two branches. So something has probably happened to some_file.txt on HEAD that cause this conflict with the version on other_branch

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm confused (obviously) about why changes that only happened in HEAD would produce conflicts when I merge in other_branch. Nothing changed in other_branch so there shouldn't have been a place where a change happened in both branches to product conflicts.

Comment: What does the log say if you add -p? What does the merge conflict look like?

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Magnus Skog's answer and your question:

> I assumed that because the file was
>   only changed in one branch that there
>   wouldn't be any conflicts. Why are
>   there conflicts? Is there a way to see
>   what will conflict (and why) before I
>   run git merge?

In such cases I would mostly do:

```
git checkout other_branch some_file.txt
```

Then do

```
git diff --cached some_file.txt
```

to see the diffs and you can easily see if you get merge conflicts. If you also wanted to just "merge" the file alone, you can `git commit` now.

This is the approach I take when seeing differences in certain file(s) and also merging specific file(s)